# I cant find my .gvimrc file in the $HOME folder in windows

Tags: c++, vim

I cant find my .gvimrc or the .vimrc file in windows
im using windows 10

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to create that file.

Comment: where should i make it?

Comment: I would believe in your userprofile directory.

Comment: Where you are looking for it. [here are some generic guidelines](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the vimrc file existence or not you can do:

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

Then make your changes and finally save them.